# How can I create popup window by jquery to external page and get a value from it to the parent page when I click a button there?

Tags: jquery, popupwindow

How can I create popup window by jquery to external page that contain a form and get a value from that external page to the parent page when I click a button there?

Comment: Is the external page on your server within the same domain etc. If not, you can't!

Comment: Do you mean window as browser window or as modal (like lightbox) window?

Comment: yes in the same domain, I prefer modal.

Answer (score 5):

There are lot of plugins for you. So have a look

1. [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)
2. [Fancy Box](http://fancybox.net/)
3. [ColorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)
4. [Lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)
5. [Thickbox - outdated](http://thickbox.net/)

[Also Google in Stack Over Flow](https://www.google.com/search?q=using%20webrequest%20asp.net&oq=using%20webrequest%20asp.net&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=site%20stackoverflow.com%20jquery%20popup&oq=site%20stackoverflow.com%20jquery%20pop&gs_l=serp.3.0.33i21.749204.751124.6.752692.10.10.0.0.0.0.320.2634.2-9j1.10.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.756ksFfCRvI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=8d44242ae547b3f7&bpcl=38625945&biw=1280&bih=935)

In order to get a value from popup to child

In Parent Page

```
  function SetPopUpData(val){

   //your logic here
  }
```

In Popup Page

```
 function SendDataToParent(){
  var data='some value';

  window.parent.SetPopUpData(data); // this will call the parent page's function
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For creating the pop-up menu, use Fancy Box plugin.
2. For getting the value from the external page, use AJAX to send a request and receive the response asynchronously.