# Popup in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-plugins, popup

After some search in **google** , finally  I decided that the below are the good **popup plugins in JQuery** with cross browser support.

1. **bpopup** [bpopup](http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/)
2. **Colorbox** [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)
3. **Lightbox_me** [Lightbox_me](http://www.freshdesignweb.com/demo/index.php?p=1379320109)

But I have tried those plugin's and nothing seems to works as show in the demo for cross browse support.

**My need :**

**1.** I have two buttons like transfer , conference

**2.** I need to create a popup . The content will be the **JSP** inside the **Iframe** and show this in the popup

**What I have tried** in **bpopup** as ,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- <script src="colorbox-master/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
<script src="bpopup-master/jquery.bpopup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">



    // DOM Ready
   $(function() {

       // Binding a click event
       // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
       $('#my-button').bind('click', function(e) {

       // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
       e.preventDefault();

       // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
       //$('#content').bPopup();

       $('#content').bPopup({
           content:'iframe', //'ajax', 'iframe' or 'image'
           contentContainer:'.content',
           loadUrl:'Mypage.jsp' //Uses jQuery.load()
       });

       });

   });





function showPopup(){
    alert("show popup");
    //$.colorbox({href:"thankyou.html"});
    //$.colorbox({href:"DatePicker.jsp"});
    $('#content').bPopup();
}
//$('#content').colorbox({href:"thankyou.html"});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id='content' style="display : none">

</div>
<!-- <input type="button" onclick="showPopup()" value='showpop'/> -->
<input type="button" id="my-button" value='showpop'/>
</body>
</html>
```

But it does not show the **UI** , as shown in the demo. I got the UI as ,

[image]

The other two also not helped.

Hope our stack users will help to find a good solution for my requirement.

Comment: Have you included the required css files?
Edit: nm, just noticed bpopup doesn't provide any css files. (which I find odd)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038619/how-can-i-create-popup-window-by-jquery-to-external-page-and-get-a-value-from-it/14038636#14038636

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example of the problem?  Or more specifically describe in what way it's not working?

Comment: Did you try jQuery UI dialog?

Comment: Btw the best popup is http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use http://jqueryui.com/dialog/
Its the most commen popup and you can code yourself out of eny issue :)

**Edit** You can load enything into your iframe

```
<div id="dialog" title="iframe">
    <iframe src=""/>
</div>

$("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    height: 440,
    width: 388,
    dialogClass: 'overlay',
    show: "fade",
});

 $("#dialog").dialog("open");
```

Comment: Thanks for a a quick reply . How I can load a jsp inside an Iframe and show this inside a popup ?

Comment: This is the best one. `+1` for you .